# Use enable_if with two levels of templating

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I want to use `enable_if` to define a class for certain types. Among these types, I need to use some templated types, and I am unable to make it work. Here is a MWE:

The templated class `A`:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void> class A;
```

Its specialization for some simple types, such as integral types here, can be defined as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A<T, std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{ ... };
```

Now I define a bunch of templated types:

```
template<typename U> class X {...};
template<typename U> class Y {...};
```

**How should I proceed to specialize my class `A` for types `X` and `Y`?**

Two attempts that do not work:

1. With the following, declaring a object of type `A<X<int> >` for instance yields an error `incomplete type`:

   ```
   template<typename U>
   template<typename T>
   class A<T, std::enable<std::is_same<T, X<U> >::value 
                       || std::is_same<T, Y<U> >::value>::type> 
   { ... };
   ```
2. With the following, the error is `'T' is not a template`.

   ```
   template<typename U>
   template<typename T>
   class A<T<U>, std::enable<std::is_same<T, X>::value 
                          || std::is_same<T, Y>::value>::type>
   { ... };
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X` and `Y` are *class templates*, not types. Your compiler is correctly complaining about using a type as a class template in you second example.

If you want a specialization for them

```
template<typename>
class A;

template<typename T>
class A<X<T>> : A_for_XY<X<T>> {};

template<typename T>
class A<Y<T>> : A_for_XY<Y<T>> {};
```